# Bash - Insert a line after/before a Match in XML

Tags: xml, shell, sed

I have this line in XML

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

and I wanted to insert the below line after the "<application"

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

So the final output looks like

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

I tried sed command as below and it didn't do anything.

```
sed -i '/<application>/a\ android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ' filename.xml
```

Tried the below and it adds the required line in the next line. But I would like to have that immediately after the application.

```
sed -i '/<application/a android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"' filename.xml
```

Comment: Consider using xmlstarlet (or another XML-aware tool) rather than `sed`. But if you _are_ going to use sed, you need to _show us the sed command that didn't work_ so we can inspect it to figure out _why_.

Comment: (also, to build a good answer with XMLStarlet, we'd need a document complete enough to show the xmlns declarations and the path from the root to the target element, not just one line out-of-context).

Comment: I've added the command I'm using @Charles Duffy

Comment: `<application yadda yadda>` is not `<application>`, so no surprises there.

Comment: To be clear, any answer that's built using XML-unaware tools will be _a bad one_. `sed` is not capable of making robust edits to XML, because sed can't _understand_ XML, and XML is an extremely powerful format. You can have part of your document where `<application>` needs to be written `<foo:application>`, or your document can be set to make `App` mean the same thing as `application`, or you can have part of your document where things that _look_ like XML elements are really just string components, or any number of other weird things can be configured and `sed` won't understand any of them.

Comment: So you really, _really_, **really** shouldn't be trying to use sed to edit XML at all in the first place. But at least there _is_ enough information to answer the immediate question now.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `<application>` won't match `<application key=value>`.

---

#### Addressing the immediate question: Why didn't `a` append a line?

Change your code to instead search for `<application[ >]` and this is no longer an issue:

```
fragment='<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">'

sed -e '/<application[ >]/a\ android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"' <<<"$fragment"
```

...correctly (insofar as the problem was the `a` operation not triggering and appending a line) emits:

```xml
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

However, this is by no means guaranteed to emit a valid XML document. Using `sed` to edit XML is innately, unfixably broken and should never be done by anyone.

---

#### Speaking to intent: Adding attributes on the existing line

Insofar as your real goal is not to append an additional line following an element, but to *add attributes* to an existing element, something closer to correct (within the innate, unavoidable unreliability of using structure-unaware tools to edit structured data) might look like:

```
sed -re 's!<application([> ])!<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"\1!'
```

Comment: sed -i '/<application/a android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"' AndroidManifest.xml


I've used the above command and it just adds the lines in the next line as below.

    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Is it possible to add immediately after the 1st application

Comment: Yes, it does add the immediate next line, because that's what your question asked for; like I told you, `sed` doesn't understand XML, and it's the wrong tool to use for this job. That's your problem -- I'm not the person who insists on using the wrong tool.

Comment: @Hellboy, ...that said, if you want a "good" answer using sed, _extend your question_ to show enough of the XML to let someone actually write and test a good answer on their own. Show the whole block before the edit, show the whole block _after_ the edit.